# Why the JVM omit the Annotation

Tags: java, annotations

i am debugging a application using OSGi, i terribly find out that if the Annotation class is missing, the class loader would omit that annotation, if i call the method.getAnnotations(), no exception, but return nothing.

i don't get it, but i do want to know if there is any way to make the JVM throw a Exception.
is there any option for starting the JVM?

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD}) 
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
@Before 
public @interface Secured { 
   /** Priority **/ public int order() default 0; 
   /** Mapping **/ public String value() default "profile/validate"; 
   /** Required **/ public boolean required() default true; 
   public String role() default "L1"; 
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: YES, i am using Felix, now i am not sure it's felix or JVM's probelm.

@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Before
public @interface Secured {
 /** Priority **/
 public int order() default 0;
 /** Mapping **/
 public String value() default "profile/validate";
 /** Required **/
 public boolean required() default true;
 
 public String role() default "L1";
}

Comment: show us how you are calling getAnnotation, and the method are are calling it on.

Comment: 1, Use felix bundle classloader load the Class,
Class clazz = app.getClassLoader().loadClass(name);
2, Iterate mathods,
for(Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()){...}
3, for every method, call, 
for(Annotation entryRefAnno : method.getAnnotations()){...},

the method defination is: 
@Entry(value="sayHi")
@Secured(role="L1")
public void sayHi(Event e){
 logger.debug("sayHi");
 e.setForward("sample1/sayHi");  
}

if Secured the annotation class is not imported by the bundle, method.getAnnotations(), return only one Annotation, @Entry.

i am using jdk1.6.17, felix 2.0.1, fedora 12

Comment: well, the answer is JDK omit the annotation by default, it works in that way!

Answer (score 3):

is your annotation retained at runtime? that is it have the [@Retetntion annotation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Retention.html) set to RUNTIME:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface YourAnnotation
```

Answer (score 3):

Every annotation has a retention defined to it. Retention basically means, in which contexts should the JVM save the annotation. Different values can be seen [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html). The default behavior is `CLASS` retention policy, which means the annotations are in the .class files, but aren't used by the JVM. What you want is `RUNTIME`, whose meaning is clear I guess. Also, there's a `SOURCE` policy, for annotations that are only relevant during compile-time.

To set the retention policy, you have to annotate the annotation (meta-meta, anyone?), using `@Retention`, which you can read more about [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Retention.html).

The [Java annotation tutorial](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html) has a bit more information about this.